# Parameters estimation in custom chi-squared distribution

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameterization, chi-squared-distribution

For modeling purposes, I need to add a parameter (denoted by $\alpha$) allowing us to control the location of a Chi-squared distribution (instead of always beginning at 0). The probability density function taking into account this modification writes
$$
f(x;k,\alpha)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{(x-\alpha)^{k/2-1}\exp{\{-(x-\alpha)/2\}}}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} & x-\alpha>0,\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then, given $n$ samples (say $n=1000$ for instance) generated from the above two-parameters $\chi^2(k,\alpha)$ distribution, I would like to both estimate the parameters $k$ and $\alpha$. The standard approach for doing this is the maximum likelihood method.

However, when calculating the expression for estimating the $\alpha$ parameter, the corresponding function seems to be a bit difficult to maximize:
$$
\left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^n \log{(x_i-\alpha)}+\frac{n\alpha}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \frac{nk\log{(2)}}{2} - n\log{\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right)}. \qquad (1)
$$
To illustrate this difficulty, I put below two figures drawing the expression $(1)$ in function of $\alpha$ for $n=1000$ samples distributed with $\alpha=3$ and different values of the parameter $k$. In the summations of $(1)$, the terms for which $x-\alpha \leq 0$ are omitted because of the logarithm.

[image]

[image]

From some values of $\alpha$, a maximum value is clearly reached. But for some other ones, it is less clear. Please could you help me to find what's wrong or if there is another way to get an estimate of the parameter $\alpha$?

Comment: Could you explain why you find this "unusable" to estimate $\alpha$?  You have written down a perfectly well-defined continuous function of $(k,\alpha)$ (for all positive $k$ and all $\alpha$ less than the smallest $x_i$) and it's not hard to show it has an upper bound, so it must have a maximum.

Comment: As I always seem to be saying in these situations, *try drawing it* -- do it for $k=2$ (and some small simple sample -- which data you definitely need to consider even at $k=2$); then perhaps see if you can draw it at $k=3$.

Comment: If there are any terms for which $x-\alpha\le 0$, then such an $\alpha$ is invalid--it is outside the range of legitimate possible values of that parameter.  Throwing out those terms is wrong: you shouldn't even be doing such a calculation.  And what are you plotting?  The graphs don't seem to be related to any search for a maximum, because their titles specify values of $(k,\alpha)$: what are you varying??

Comment: I am aware of that but it would mean in that case the estimate of $\alpha$ is just the minimum among all samples? It's probably not a good estimator because when some samples are missing on the left for instance. I'm varying the parameter $\alpha$ along the x-axis. The values mentioned in the titles are those that were used for generating samples.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "all samples"?  You have *one* sample of $n=1000$ observations.  The meaning of your plots is questionable because the log likelihood you wrote is a nice smooth function of $(k,\alpha)$ but your graphs have a lot of sharp wiggles and a non-differentiable peak, indicating they are not computing the log likelihood correctly.

Comment: Sorry, by "all samples" I mean $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. I think that the waves at the end of the curves is due to the fact that I omit the $x_i$ such that $x_i \leq \alpha$ (as I said before). To avoid that, the curve should stops at $\alpha=\min_{i=1}^n{\{x_i\}}$. But in that case, that would correspond to the estimate of $\alpha$ but it won't be an accurate estimate when they are missing measurements in the left of the distribution...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "missing measurements," because your question doesn't mention that possibility. However, I notice you are looking at the cases $k=1$ and $k=2$. These are difficult ones, both theoretically and numerically, because the density reaches a sharp peak at $x=\alpha$ (and I suspect that causes the MLE of $\alpha$ to be the minimum of the $x_i$ in many cases, which places it on the boundary). You would do yourself a favor by working first with larger values of $k\gg 2$. The value of $\alpha$ you select doesn't matter. Your graphs are incorrect: check the arithmetic.

Comment: I had added the figures for $k=3$ and $k=6$ in an separate post but you have removed them (sorry, I did not know how to add them in a different way). The value of $\alpha$ does matter for me and it must be enough accurate (maybe you meant $k$). For instance, imagine a situation where $\alpha^*=3$ but $\min_{i=1}^n=2.5$ (there can be some noise). Since the MLE of $\alpha$ seems to be the minimum of the $x_i$, the estimate of $\alpha$ is "far" from $\alpha^*$. This situation can occurs when $n$ is small. But if it is not possible to get a more accurate estimate of $\alpha$, I will take it...

Comment: My impression (as non-native speaker) is that "sample" can have very different meaning in English (as opposed to American). I often see british autors writing "sample" meaning "a data point". The meaning surely comes from laboratory fields? where taking "a sample" is really a data point.